# calc can't calculate the width of parent's div?

Tags: html, css

```css
 body{width:400px;}
.bd{ padding:0 50px 0 80px; height:100px; }
.middle{ float:left; width:100%; height:80px;background:blue; }
.left{ float:left; width:180px; height:80px;background:#0c9;margin-left:-320px;}
```

```html
<div class="bd">
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
</div>
```

The 100% width of bd1 is `(400-50-80)=270px`, and `270+50=320px`,so
`-calc(100% + 50px)=-320px`.
Why `margin-left:-320px;` can't be changed as `margin-left:-calc(100% + 50px);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css doesn't allow the syntax `margin-left: -calc(100% + 50px);`. use `margin-left: calc(-100% - 50px);` Instead.

Comment: Note that one could also do `calc((100% + 50px) * -1)`

Answer (score 0):

**Use of :**

```
 margin-left:calc(-100% - 50px);
```

```css
 body{
    width:400px;
}
.bd1{ 
    padding:0 50px 0 80px;
    height:100px; 
 }
.middle1{ 
    float:left; 
    width:100%;
     height:80px;
     background:blue; 
 }
.left1{ float:left;
 width:180px; 
 height:80px;
 background:#0c9;
 margin-left:calc(-100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bd1">
  <div class="middle1">middle</div>
  <div class="left1">left</div>
</div>
```